# Não executar linha de comando

Tags: lua

Bom, estou fazendo um programa com o [VCLua](http://vclua.luaforge.net/) e percebi que depois de compilar, mesmo com a interface grafica, ele executa o modo de linha de comando, como faço para evitar isso? Executando apenas o programa.
Compileri com o SrLua.
O programa é basicamente isso:

```
require("vcl")
form = VCL.Form("Form")
form._ = {position="podesktopcenter", width=480, height=240, caption="Compiler", BorderStyle="bsDialog"}
form:ShowModal()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o `wsrlua.exe` no lugar do `srlua.exe` e o console não abrirá automaticamente.

A respectiva linha de comando ficaria assim:

```
glue.exe wsrlua.exe meuscript.lua meuexecutavel.exe
```

Notar que basicamente foi trocado o executável utilizado. Em [webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/) o "pai da criança" **[@lhf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1642)** :) faz uma referência para a versão pré-compilada para Windows, fornecida por [Daniel Quintela](http://www.soongsoft.com).

Mais especificamente, quando escrita esta resposta, a versão atual pré-compilada era a 5.1 do SRLua, disponibilizada em **[www.soongsoft.com/lhf/lua/5.1/srlua.tgz](http://www.soongsoft.com/lhf/lua/5.1/srlua.tgz)**. O executável se encontra na pasta `release`.

Answer (score 0):

Para os casos em que é necessário fazer uso do [`os.execute`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.execute), o mesmo abre uma janela de terminal que fica em aberta pois a execução ocorre na mesma.

Para contornar isto, uma solução passa por fazer uso da biblioteca [`winapi`](http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html#shell_exec), onde podemos utilizar a função [`shell_exec()`](http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html#shell_exec) que nos permite realizar a mesma operação mas sem aparecer a janela de terminal dado a mesma ser "suprimida".

Comment: No meu caso não utilizo nada relacionado a os, o winapi continua servindo?